# A fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\emptyset \not = X\subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ be convex and compact and let $\cal{A}$ be a family of affine maps from $\Bbb{R}^n$ into $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $X$ is invariant under each element of $\cal A$ and $f\circ g = g\circ f$ for any $f, g \in \cal A$. I am trying to show that elements of $\cal A$ have  a common fixed point which is in $X$.

Any idea or references would be helpful.

Comment: That is Kakutani's fixed point theorem restricted to finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: First show that every finite subfamily $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ has a common fixed point (take a limit of the Cesàro averages).  The set $F(\mathcal{E})$ of common fixed points of $\mathcal{E}$ is therefore a non-empty closed set.  The collection of $F(\mathcal{E})$ for all finite subfamilies $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is a nested net of non-empty closed sets, which by compactness has a non-empty intersection.

Comment: @Joseph: How do you apply Kakutani's theorem in this case !?

Comment: @kian. I was talking about something I have seen called the Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem which generalizes this result to topological vector spaces. There is another fixed point theorem also called the Kakutani fixed point theorem which you might have been looking at instead.

Comment: The Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem states that if $V$ is a Hausdorff topological vector space, $X\subseteq V$ is a compact convex subset of $V$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is a commuting family of continuous affine maps from $X$ to $X$, then $\mathcal{A}$ has a common fixed point.